# invalid assignment left-hand side (Not hyphenated variable name)

Tags: variable-assignment, railo, cfwheels

I've got a fresh install of CFWheels on Railo and the first time I tried to initiate a model I get this error `invalid assignment left-hand side` on the line where I do that. My code is as follows:

```
<cfset newUser = model('User').new() />
```

I have a users table in my DB, I've tried adding/removing the User.cfc from the models dir (just to see if something was going on with that). I've fiddled with settings, etc and I always get the error. I can run a query against the table manually by doing:

```
<cfquery name="test" datasource="app"> SELECT * FROM Users</cfquery>
```

I get the expected result. So I know my DB connection is good, my Wheels conventions should automatically select the correct table, (I mean I'm not getting the wheels table not found error) so I suspect something is up with Railo. (I'm used to working in CF not Railo).

Thoughts on what might be going on? I've read some stuff about the NULL Support option and a bug in Railo, but I don't think this should be causing that. (NULL Support is set to "Complete Support")

Trace can be viewed at: http://app.snapbought.com/user/create My model declaration is on line 9 of the User.cfc controller.

Comment: I don't know if CFWheels supports full null support in Railo, but it's worth checking.  Can you post the actual stack trace of the error.  It's possible you're mistaken about the actual line of code that the error is occurring on.

Comment: As noted, it's set to Complete Support. The trace is insanely long, but I can if you want. I can view in the Tag Context Array the first non-default wheels code in there is the line where I call the model. Additionally, if I set `newUser` to a random string or number the error goes away. Do you still want to see the trace?

Comment: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-2194 Apparently setting Railo to complete support breaks `null = x` type variable associations and cfwheels has a lot of them.

Comment: Ah, I see.  CFWheels is actually using variables *named* "null".  Yep, that won't work with full null support since "null" becomes a keyword.  When I mentioned earlier you should "check" I meant you should check CFWheels' documentation to see if it's supported. Moot now though since we know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments on the question, the code in the CFWHeels framework is not currently compatible with Railo's "Full null support" option.  Turn it off to use CFWheels.

Comment: So, "Full null support" seems like it would make more things work not less. I guess my side question is, does that mean CF doesn't have full null support. Why would Railo deviate from something CF is doing? They are both cfml languages and I would think Railo would want to mimick CF as closely as posssible. Also, I can't change that setting as it's a server admin setting and not a web admin setting and this is a shared server.

Comment: No, Adobe ColdFusion has never had full null support.  Hibernate support in CF9 introduced partial support.  That's why the Railo admin says "CFML Default" next to "Partial Support".  Railo deviated because they feel it is better and that's why they created a flag for it.  Railo also probably has less interest in copying Adobe CF than you think.  I am surprised your server admin would enable that setting on a shared server. A LOT of  existing code is incompatible with it. I would ask them to reconsider. Note, there is no Application.cfc setting for this since it is compile-time.

Comment: I've sent the request and he said ok as long as it doesn't break anyone elses stuff.